# Direct xtrace output elsewhere than stderr in zsh

Tags: zsh, debugging

In zsh, is it possible to direct the trace output from `set -x` (`set -o xtrace`) to a file descriptor other than stderr?

I'm looking for an equivalent of [`$BASH_XTRACEFD`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fXTRACEFD) or a way to emulate the same behaviour.

Comment: For reference, I had initiated a discussion to implement this in Zsh, see https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2020/msg01181.html (last reply in the thread I think). I even attempted to implement it myself, but never finished it. If someone wants to pick it up, I'll gladly help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of zsh 5.7, the answer is no. The trace output always goes to stderr.

Source: reading the source. The trace output is written to the file `xtrerr`, which looks promising, but the only assignments to `xtrerr` are to `stderr`, to a copy of it, or to `NULL`.

It should be possible to write a dynamically loadable module that sets `xtrerr`, but writing a module outside the zsh source tree is not easy.

A possible workaround is to emulate `xtrace` with a [`DEBUG`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-TRAPDEBUG) [trap](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-trap). This provides the same basic information in most cases, but I'm sure there are plenty of corner cases where `xtrace` would be hard or impossible to emulate perfectly. One difference is that the inheritance of the `xtrace` option and the inheritance of traps follow different rules in some circumstances related to functions, subshells, `emulate`, etc. Proof-of-concept:

```
trap 'print -r -- "+$0:$LINENO>$ZSH_DEBUG_CMD" >>trace_file' DEBUG
```

Or maybe a bit more sophisticated (untested):

```
zmodload zsh/system
sysopen -a -o create -u xtrace_fd trace_file
trap 'syswrite -o $xtrace_fd "+$0:$LINENO>$ZSH_DEBUG_CMD"' DEBUG
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a very simple workaround which may be useful if you want to debug only a specific function although the same idea can be applied to complete tracing with `set -x`:

When I need to debug a specific function, say `myfunc`, I open a child shell with `TRACE_FUNC=myfunc zsh -l 2> debug.err.txt` while I have set in my `~/.zshrc` something along the lines of:

```
if [ -n "${TRACE_FUNC}" ]; then
    functions -t "$TRACE_FUNC"
fi
```

You can apply the same idea by putting in your `~/.zshrc` the following:

```
if [ -n "${TRACE_ZSH}" ]; then
    set -x
fi
```

And spawn the child shell with `TRACE_ZSH=1 zsh -l 2> debug.err.txt`.

Comment: What does `functions -t` do? I can't see `-t` explained in `help functions`. Any reason to not do `TRACE_FUNC=myfunc zsh -l 2> debug.err.txt`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. I didn't find any reference in the documentation for `functions -t` as well. I've read that in [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/4fchl9/debugging_zshzshrc/d28e900). However, a reasonable explanation can be found in [this section](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-autoload) but for the builtin `autoload` and not `functions`.

Comment: Reading more closely, `help functions` says it's equivalent to `typeset`, which `help` says: `Tags  the named parameters.  Tags have no special meaning to the shell.  This flag has a  different  meaning when used with -f; see above.`

Help not helpful. ... I'd like to think of it as "traces", which indeed it does.

Comment: `functions -t <function>` will enable tracing for, and only for, the function `<function>`. It _is_ described in the documentation you linked to @DoronBehar, e.g. just do a free text search for `functions -t`. @tom-hale: the help says that `functions` is equivalent to `typeset -f` (note *-f*). So instead of `functions -t <function>` you can use `typeset -f -t <function>`; these are equivalent.